# iPhone load partial image

Tags: iphone, image, load

I need to load a part of an image into a uiimageview... for example an image that is 100x100, only display 100x50...
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

samsam is telling this

```
uiimageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
uiimageview.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,100,50);
uiimageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopLeft;
```

Comment: x and y means the starting position i.e. top left of the image on the view.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if i fully understand your intentions on that, but as far as I'm concerned, partly loading an image would probably be a lot more difficult then just loading the whole image into your imageview and setting its frame accordingly.